# MCI Device Error in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, mci

### MCI Error

*The specified file cannot be played on the specified MCI device.  The file may be corrupt, not in the correct format, or no fil*

I have used following code to create a device and play the file.

```
m_Path = _T("res\\phoneringing.mp3");
m_Video = MCIWndCreate(/*this->GetSafeHwnd()*/ m_hWnd,
AfxGetInstanceHandle(),WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|MCIWNDF_NOMENU|MCIWNDF_NOPLAYBAR,m_Path);
```

I have observed that when my application creates the device second time using MCIWndCreate it throws this error.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK those old 'multimedia' API's only work for AVIs for video and WAV for audio. You'll probably want to embed Media Player for what you want to do.